# Combination From Rows

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to check the combination of values from data its exist or not. Below code works fine buts its looks inefficient. I am looking for some good solution of this problem.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Integer data[] = {
            1, 2, 5, 1, 9, 3, 5, 3, 2
    };

    Integer combination[] = {
            1, 3 ,2
    };

    System.out.println("Result: " + combinations(data, combination));
}


public static boolean combinations(Integer dataset[], Integer combination[]) {

    boolean results[] = new boolean[combination.length];

    Integer count = 0;
    for (Integer comb : combination) {

        for (Integer data : dataset) {
            if (data.equals(comb)) {
                results[count++] = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    for (Boolean result : results) {
        if (!result) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**strong text**

Comment: If your code works and you're looking for better and more efficient solution, consider posting your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data consists of Integers which implements "Comparable", I would suggest you exploit that and construct a TreeSet and add all the data into it. You can then run a contains() to find if an element is present in the TreeSet or not.
TreeSet guarantees log(n) cost for each add, delete and contains.
Adding all elements(n) will cost you n*log(n).
Finding if 'm' elements are present will cost you m*log(n).

Comment: TreeSet.containsAll() looks efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just want to check if the combination is a subset of your data set...The order in which it appears in your data set is not important. Is that correct?

How big will be your data set? Is the data set created whenever it is required or is it maintained throughout?

If data set is large and is maintained throughout, it would be easier to search  if you can maintain it sorted.

```
for (Integer comb : combination) {
    if (Arrays.binarySearch(dataset, comb) < 0) 
        return false; //If any element is not found, return false
    }
}
return true;
```

If you can keep the combination also sorted, you can further optimize it.

```
int loc = 0;
for (Integer comb : combination) {
    loc = Arrays.binarySearch(dataset, loc, data.length, comb);
    //Since both are sorted, u can be sure that next element will be 
    //after previous element match
    if (loc < 0) 
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Even if you can't maintain a sorted array, one optimization u can do is to get rid of that boolean array and the for-loop at the bottom. Algorithm is as follows...

```
boolean isMatch = false;
for (Integer comb : combination) {
    //We will be here in two condition - 
    //  1. first iteration or previous element was found in dataset. 
    //  2. Just set to false to check next element. Reset the flag 
    boolean isMatch = false; 
    for (Integer data : dataset) {
        if (data.equals(comb)) {
            //match found for the current combination element
            isMatch = true;  
            break;
        }
    }
    //This mean one of the combination element is not there. Break out.
    if (!isMatch) break;  
}
return isMatch;
```

Comment: One correction..."return true" in the first two code blocks should be outside for loop

Answer (score 1):

Sort the dataset set which is complexity nlog(n). (Quick or merge sort maybe ? ) Then run binary search for every member of combination array over dataset. Binary search complexity log(n). When you do this for every member of combination array complexity will be nlog(n).

nlog(n) + nlog(n) = 2nlog(n) which is O(nlogn). This way your performance will be increase.

---

Code

```
public static boolean combinations(Integer dataset[], Integer combination[]) {

sort(dataset); // quick or insertion sort, nlogn


for (Integer comb : combination) { // n

    if (!binarysearch(dataset, comb)) //logn
       return false;
}  //n*logn = nlogn

return true;} //2nlogn = O(nlogn)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change from array to ArrayList and use the containsAll method. not sure if it is efficient enough but will make your code shorter.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Integer data[] = {1, 2, 5, 1, 9, 3, 5, 3, 2};
    Integer combination[] = {1,3 ,2};
    System.out.println("Result: " + combinations(data, combination));
}
public static boolean combinations(Integer dataset[], Integer combination[]) {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(dataset);
    List<Integer> comb = Arrays.asList(combination);
    return data.containsAll(comb);
}
```